# Material UI ListItem with Floating Action Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm attempting to make a simple list with a listItem that contains a button. I have the following code:

```js
import React from "react";
import darkBaseTheme from 'material-ui/styles/baseThemes/darkBaseTheme';
import MuiThemeProvider from 'material-ui/styles/MuiThemeProvider';
import getMuiTheme from 'material-ui/styles/getMuiTheme';
import Avatar from 'material-ui/Avatar';
import AccountCircle from 'material-ui/svg-icons/action/account-circle';
import ContentAdd from 'material-ui/svg-icons/content/add';
import FloatingActionButton from 'material-ui/FloatingActionButton';
import {List, ListItem} from 'material-ui/List';
import IconButton from 'material-ui/IconButton';

export default class Inbox extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
  }

  _test() {
    alert("_test");
  }

  render() {
    let that = this;

    // const iconButtonElement = (
    //   <button onClick={that._test}></button>
    // );

    const iconButtonElement = (
      <FloatingActionButton mini={true} onMouseDown={ that._test }>
        <ContentAdd />
      </FloatingActionButton>
    );

    return (
      <div className="darkContainer">
        <div className="containerBanner">

          <MuiThemeProvider muiTheme={getMuiTheme(darkBaseTheme)}>

            <div className="column5">
              { iconButtonElement }

              <br></br>

              <List>

                <ListItem
                  leftAvatar={<Avatar icon={ <AccountCircle /> } />}
                  rightIconButton={iconButtonElement}
                  primaryText="Jon Doe"
                  onTouchTap={that._test}
                />

              </List>

            </div>
          </MuiThemeProvider>

        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The button I insert before the list successfully calls the onMouseDown function, but the button contained within the listItem fails to. I can't seem to figure out why this is happening and how I can make the button in the listItem work.

I'm wondering if anyone has suggestions as to how I might fix this? Example code would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so I was able to fix this by changing onMouseDown to onTouchTap. I don't see this as a property on the [Floating Action Button docs](http://www.material-ui.com/#/components/floating-action-button) so if anyone has a better solution I'd love to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm still very new to React, so I don't know if this is correct style, but I found that since the element is a function, you can pass in the handler as a parameter. If you have more than one parameter, I think you would pass in 'props' or 'this' instead of 'handleOnMouseDown'.

```
const iconButtonElement = (handleOnMouseDown) => {
      render <FloatingActionButton mini={true} onMouseDown={handleOnMouseDown}>
        <ContentAdd />
      </FloatingActionButton>
```

}

here is my code that worked for me

```
const iconButtonElement = (handleTouchTap) => {
  return <IconButton
    touch={true}
    tooltip="star"
    tooltipPosition="bottom-left"
    onTouchTap={handleTouchTap}
  >
    <ToggleStarHalf color={yellow700} />
  </IconButton>
}

class PersonItem extends Component {
  constructor(props, context) {
    super(props, context);
  }

  handleUpdateStar() {
    console.log('handleUpdateStar');
  }

  handleClick() {
    console.log('handleClick');
  }

  render() {    
    const { person } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <ListItem
          onTouchTap={this.handleClick.bind(this)}
          leftAvatar={
            <img 
              alt={person.name}
              src={this.thumb(person.image)}
              className="face"
            />
          }
          rightIconButton={iconButtonElement(this.handleUpdateStar.bind(this))}
          primaryText={person.name}
          secondaryText={person.desc}
          secondaryTextLines={2}
        />
        <Divider inset={false} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```